# How to add custom authorization in .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-authorization

I have ASP.NET Core MVC application using NET 5. Only authenticated users are allowed to access the application. The authorization policy below takes care of it.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                   .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Email)
                   .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
                   .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name)
                   .RequireClaim(IdentityClaimTypes.IdToken)
                   .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                   .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicy));
        }) 
     }
```

The controllers are also using `AuthorizeRoles` attribute to check access based on roles.

```
public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(params string[] roles) : base()
    {
        if (roles.Length > 0)
        {
            Roles = string.Join(",", roles);
        }
    }
}


[AuthorizeRoles("ClientAdmin")]
public class WorkItemClientsController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IClientWorkItemService _clientWorkItemService;

    public WorkItemClientsController(IClientWorkItemService clientWorkItemService)
    {
        _clientWorkItemService = clientWorkItemService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("workitems/{workItemID}/clients")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index([FromRoute(Name = "workItemID")] int workItemID)
    {
        
    }
 }
```

The application has few actions that need to be further authorized based on the user's data in the database. I have the following

```
public class WorkItemRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

public class WorkItemAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<WorkItemRequirement>
{
  protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, WorkItemRequirement requirement)
    {
       //check if logged in user can access this route based on workitemid from the route, if true then return context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}

public class WorkItemAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{       
  public WorkItemAuthorizeAttribute()
  { 
    Policy = "WorkItemPolicy"
  }
}
```

I will add `WorkItemAuthorizeAttribute` to require action methods.

What I am missing here is how `WorkItemAuthorizeAttribute` will know which handler to invoke. In this case its `WorkItemAuthorizationHandler`.
What do I need to change/add in AuthorizationPolicyBuilder in startup.cs to make this association?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything you can find in official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
basically as you said you need to modify your policy to include your `WorkItemRequirement` like that:

```
.Requirements.Add(new WorkItemRequirement());
```

That will 'glue' `Policy` in your Attribute with your AuthorizationHandler